# Uncompress() of 'zlib' returns Z_DATA_ERROR

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I made a simple function which takes a gzipped file, and extracts somewhere. For testing purposes i'm using a text file which had been gzipped through a generic utility *gzip*.
But for some reason the [Uncompress()](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/manual.html#uncompress) returns an error [Z_DATA_ERROR](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/manual.html#Z_DATA_ERROR).

I walked in a debugger till the function, and it surely gets the right data(a whole file content, it's just 37 bytes), so it seems to be one of two: the frightful zlib-bug is stealing your time for now, or I am missing something important and then I really sorry.

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

int UngzipFile(FILE* Dest, FILE* Source){
    #define IN_SIZE 256
    #define OUT_SIZE 2048
    bool EOFReached=false;
    Bytef in[IN_SIZE];
    Bytef out[OUT_SIZE];
    while(!EOFReached){//for no eof
        uLong In_ReadCnt = fread(in,1,IN_SIZE,Source);//read a bytes from a file to input buffer
        if(In_ReadCnt!=IN_SIZE){
            if(!feof(Source) ){
                perror("ERR");
                return 0;
            }
            else    EOFReached=true;
        }
        uLong OutReadCnt = OUT_SIZE;//upon exit 'uncompress' this will have actual uncompressed size
        int err = uncompress(out, &OutReadCnt, in, In_ReadCnt);//uncompress the bytes to output
        if(err!=Z_OK){
            printf("An error ocurred in GZIP, errcode is %i\n", err);
            return 0;
        }
        if(fwrite(out,1,OutReadCnt,Dest)!=OUT_SIZE ){//write to a 'Dest' file
            perror("ERR");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* In = fopen("/tmp/Kawabunga.gz", "r+b");
    FILE* Out = fopen("/tmp/PureKawabunga", "w+b");
    if(!In || !Out){
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }
    if(!UngzipFile(Out,In))printf("An error encountered\n");
}
```

Comment: uncompress() is for the raw data compressed with the deflate algoritmn, it does not know about the gzip format.

Comment: @nos I just thought about it too. For now I'm looking for a header specification, if I find one, I'll post a working solution here. Though I wonder: there _should be_ something working already...

Comment: You can use the gzopen() function on the page you linked to. Or use the inflate() function. The gzip format is documented in  RFC 1952

Comment: Really, the gzopen() allows to read a file like if it was uncompressed one. @nos it would be good if you're post your two comments like an answer, it's the solution!

Comment: No, `uncompress()` is for the zlib format, not raw deflate.  But, yes, it does not know about the gzip format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `inflate()`, not `uncompress()`.  In `inflateInit2()`, you can specify the gzip format (or auto-detection of the zlib or gzip format).  See the documentation in zlib.h.

You can take the source code for `uncompress()` in zlib and make a simple change to use `inflateInit2()` instead of `inflateInit()` to create your own `gzipuncompress()`, or whatever you'd like to call it.

Comment: I've tried before the _inflate()_, but it's [manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) too confusing. At first there written, that _zlib_ and _gzip_ format is different. But it also says, that gzip is supported too, then where should I point which a format should be used? Nor functions nor structs have anything about this. May be it can do some kind of auto-recognition? Then which is minimal block of characters can I threw to the _inflate()_ function? This man doesn't seems to be written by people, who wanted that someone tried to touch the library :D

Comment: As I said, with `inflateInit2()`.  From the manual: "windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip decoding. Add 32 to windowBits to enable zlib and gzip decoding with automatic header detection, or add 16 to decode only the gzip format (the zlib format will return a Z_DATA_ERROR)."