# adapt zlib zpipe for char arrays

Tags: c++, zlib

I have a char array (char* dataToInflate) obtained from a .gz file I would like to inflate into another char array.

I don't know the original decompressed size, so I believe this means I can't use the `uncompress` function that is within the zlib library, since per the manual:

> The size of the uncompressed data must have been saved previously by the compressor and transmitted to the decompressor by some mechanism outside the scope of this compression library.

I have looked at the zpipe.C example (https://zlib.net/zpipe.c), and the inf function here looks suitable but I'm not sure how to adapt it from FILEs to char arrays.

Does anyone know how or have any other ideas for inflating a char array into another char array?

**Update:**

I read here: [Uncompress() of 'zlib' returns Z_DATA_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809458/uncompress-of-zlib-returns-z-data-error)

that for arrays obtained through gzip files, `uncompress` isn't suitable.

I found that I could decompress the file in full using gzopen, gzread and gzclose like so:

```
    gzFile in_file_gz = gzopen(gz_char_array, "rb");
    char unzip_buffer[8192];
    int unzipped_bytes;
    std::vector<char> unzipped_data;

    while (true) {
        unzipped_bytes = gzread(in_file_gz, unzip_buffer, 8192);
        if (unzipped_bytes > 0) {
            unzipped_data.insert(unzipped_data.end(), unzip_buffer, unzip_buffer + unzipped_bytes);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    gzclose(in_file_gz)
```

but I would also like to be able to decompress the char array. I tried with the following method:

```
void test_inflate(Byte *compr, uLong comprLen, Byte *uncompr, uLong *uncomprLen) {

    int err;
    z_stream d_stream; /* decompression stream */
    d_stream.zalloc = NULL;
    d_stream.zfree = NULL;
    d_stream.opaque = NULL;
    d_stream.next_in = compr;
    d_stream.avail_in = 0;
    d_stream.next_out = uncompr;
    err = inflateInit2(&d_stream, MAX_WBITS + 16);
    CHECK_ERR(err, "inflateInit");

    while (d_stream.total_out < *uncomprLen && d_stream.total_in < comprLen) {
        d_stream.avail_in = d_stream.avail_out = 1; /* force small buffers */
        err = inflate(&d_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        if (err == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;
        CHECK_ERR(err, "inflate");
    }
    err = inflateEnd(&d_stream);
    *uncomprLen = d_stream.total_out;

}
```

but in the while loop, the inflate method returns Z_STREAM_END before the file has decompressed in full.

The method returns successfully, but only a partial buffer has been written.
I put a minimum working example here:
https://github.com/alanjtaylor/zlibExample

if anyone has time to look.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you studied [the manual](https://zlib.net/manual.html)?

Comment: _"I don't know the original decompressed size, so I believe this means I can't use the decompress function that is within the zlib library."_ I'm not convinced that's true. Can you please quote the relevant documentation passage claiming this?

Comment: Perhaps there is a workaround, but this is the passage that I was referring to:

"The size of the uncompressed data must have been saved previously by the compressor and transmitted to the decompressor by some mechanism outside the scope of this compression library."

Comment: Which function is that line from?

Comment: uncompress. 
Apologies, I meant "uncompress function" in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have on github, "zippedFile.gz" is a concatenation of seven independent gzip members. This is permitted by the gzip standard ([RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952)), and the zlib `gz*` file functions automatically process all of the members.

[pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) will show all of the members:

```
% pigz -lvt zippedFile.gz 
method    check    timestamp    compressed   original reduced  name
gzip 8  e323586d  ------ -----      616431    1543643   60.1%  zippedFile
gzip 8  7efd928a  ------ -----      369231     921600   59.9%  <...>
gzip 8  7ebd8b2a  ------ -----      919565    2319970   60.4%  <...>
gzip 8  3dd6e2ba  ------ -----      619670    1549236   60.0%  <...>
gzip 8  c1cb922e  ------ -----      600367    1533151   60.8%  <...>
gzip 8  a9fef06c  ------ -----      620250    1541785   59.8%  <...>
gzip 8  43b57506  ------ -----      623081    1555203   59.9%  <...>
```

The `inflate*` functions will only process one member at a time, in order to let you know with `Z_STREAM_END` that the member decompressed successfully and that the CRC checked out ok.

All you need to do is put your inflator in a loop and run it until the input is exhausted, or you run into an error. (This is noted in the [documentation for `inflateInit2` in zlib.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h#L867).)

There are a few issues with your inflator, but I understand that it is just an initial attempt to get things working, so I won't comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! :) 
I updated my example on github. I decided to use uncompress2 and change it to ```inflateInit2``` and changed the source char array to a vector. It works now!

Comment: Your guess: `buffer_out_length = len * 10;` won't always work. The maximum compression ratio of the deflate format is 1032:1. It is not practical to always allocate a buffer a thousand times the size of the input. You will need to modify `gzipuncompress2` to increase the size of the output buffer inside the loop as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reviewing it! I updated it with a modification in the do while loop but it doesn't work. In my cout statements, it prints out the correct buffer lengths but my vector check at the end doesn't work. I'm concerned that I didn't place ```stream.next_out = dest;``` in the correct place?

Comment: What you have on github currently has nothing in the loop to grow the destination. Instead it just keeps overwriting the destination. Your source is a vector. Make your destination a vector as well, since C++ can grow the vector for you as needed.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion to make the destination a vector, I updated it with a working version now :)

Answer (score 1):

`uncompress` is indeed designed for where you have all that information ready. It's a utility function.

It *probably* wraps `inflate`, which is what you want to use. You have to run it in a loop and manage the "stream" parameters yourself by repeatedly pointing to the next chunk of buffered data until it's all been eaten.

There's [an annotated example in the documentation](https://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  Unfortunately I read that the ```uncompress``` function is not suitable for arrays obtained through gz files. I'm still having some problems with this and have updated the opening post to reflect this.

Comment: I read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809458/uncompress-of-zlib-returns-z-data-error


It is because of the inflateInit method which is not suitable for gzip format. I tried Mark Adler's suggestion of using the source code and changing inflateInit for inflateInit2. The code compiles and runs but it gives me the same result as in my opening post -- only a part of the buffer is saved into the output destination.